# Pass an object's function to another of its functions

Tags: javascript

This is what I have:

```
var Person = function(fname, lname) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
    };

    Person.prototype = {
        getFullName: function() {
            return this.fname + " " + this.lname;
        },
        doStuff: function(stuff) {
            return stuff();
        }
    };

var john = new Person("John", "Doe");
```

The `doStuff` function works with other functions, but doing the following returns `undefined undefined`:

```
console.log(john.doStuff(john.getFullName));
```

What's wrong with what what I have and how can I change it to make it work?
Thanks.

Comment: Try doing `console.log(this)` in your `getFullName()` function and see what it retuns ;)

Comment: If it will only receive its own methods, you can just pass a string `john.doStuff("getFullName")`, and then do `return this[stuff]();`. Or you could do both, where if you get a string, it tries to use it as a method name, otherwise it just invokes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `this` doesn't refer to the object.

You could use the [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in order to set the value of `this`:

```
john.doStuff(john.getFullName.bind(john));
```

However, that's not very flexible, therefore you could just bind it within the `doStuff` method:

```
doStuff: function(stuff) {
  return stuff.apply(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Julek If any arguments are being passed, I'd suggest using Paul's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you know `foo.doStuff`'s arg always wants to be called on `foo`, you can write this in `doStuff`

```
// ...
    doStuff: function (stuff) {
        return stuff.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
```